# EasyHook and CallWndProc

Tags: c#, hook, wndproc, easyhook

I am desperately trying and failing to hook `CallWndProc` using EasyHook.

```
Intptr addr = LocalHook.GetProcAddress("user32.dll", "CallWndProc");
```

This throws with "The given method does not exist.". So I'm guessing either `CallWndProc` isn't in user32.dll, or it's called something subtly different, or I'm missing some fundamental piece of the puzzle.

Cheers

Comment: I'd just like to point out to people who dig this up, I am yet to actually get this working even though GSerg came up with correct name for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given method does not exists.

The function is exported as `CallWindowProcA` and `CallWindowProcW` for ANSI and Unicode calls respectively.

Comment: Bonus points if you can tell me how to determine, in C#, if a process is compiled using -DUNICODE?

Comment: @acron "Compiled as unicode" doesn't actually make sense. `CallWindowProc` is designed for working with windows, which a process might not even have. But if there is a window, then [`IsWindowUnicode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633529.aspx).